# MySQL more than 1 row error

Tags: mysql

Here's what I enter in, I had to replace EXCEPT with "NOT IN". So that solved one error, but now it returns more than 1 row. I'm not exactly sure how that's bad. I'm just starting to figure out MySQL and trying examples from the book.

```
SELECT S.sname 
FROM suppliers S 
WHERE (
  (SELECT P.pid FROM parts P) NOT IN 
  (SELECT C.pid FROM catalog C WHERE C.sid = S.sid)
);

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: Thanks @IkeWalker for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.sname 
FROM suppliers S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT P.pid FROM parts P, catalog C 
WHERE P.pid = C.pid AND C.sid = S.sid)
);
```

Comment: Returns Empty Set. Also it's not selecting C.pid from catalog C

Comment: what you want to achieve? The Pid s in Parts but not in Catalog? How is that related (or is it) to Suppliers in the desired result?

Comment: there's a part ID, supplier ID, and catalog ID. Trying to find the names of suppliers who supply every part (found it catalog)

Comment: still not sure, could you show some example and desired result?